# Passing variables to another shell script at build time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script,

```
PREFIX=${PREFIX:-'D1'}
echo "PREFIX is $PREFIX"
docker run -e PREFIX=$PREFIX -it  tci-deployer /bin/bash
```

I am running this script by sourcing PREFIX parameter,

```
export PREFIX=demo
```

My Question is, I am running another script which copies the above script in another location and tries to run it, After running, PREFIX value is set to D1 inside the docker container and not the sourced one.
How can i make the another script to evaluate the value before copying it to another location, So that the correct value is obtained in the docker container?

Comment: Are you exporting the variable in same script or another. Let us know how you are doing that

Comment: I am exporting it as soon as i start the terminal, i.e. neither in any script but on the terminal before running these scripts. So in the given script it is evaluated correctly, However second script is just retaining the D1 value and not the sourced one.

Comment: It's the responsibility of the caller to make sure `PREFIX` is set to the correct value. The only other option is to hard-code `PREFIX=demo` in the script itself before copying it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the envsubst tool does about what you want. It will replace any instances of $PREFIX with the value in the current shell. It will not change the "PREFIX=${PREFIX:-'D1'}" line, though, but that can be handled somewhat by changing how the variable is initialized (using an if statement instead of the more compact form. e.g the file foo contains:

```
if [ -n "$PREFIX" ]
then
    PREFIX=${PREFIX:-D1}
fi
echo PREFIX is $PREFIX
```

and PREFIX=B in the shell, the command

```
cat foo | envsubst >foo1
```

The file foo1 will contain:

```
if [ -n "B" ]
then
    PREFIX=${PREFIX:-D1}
fi
echo PREFIX is B
```

Comment: `envsubst` doesn't ensure that values are escaped to be parsed to their literal values by the reading shell. That is to say, if you have an assignment done with `val='$(rm -rf /tmp/evil)'`, and you use `envsubst` on an input file with `val=$val`, you'll get `val=$(rm -rf /tmp/evil)`, not `val='$(rm -rf /tmp/evil)'`.

Comment: Much safer to either use NUL-delimited key=value pairs (the way `/proc/self/environ` works), or something like `printf '%q=%q\n' "$varname" "${!varname}"` for each variable.

Comment: That's a good point, I agree that it is not useful as a general purpose tool on any possible script, but I've found it to be great when want to do some simple substitution in a file like the example above.